# how to comapre two QList variables in Qt

Tags: qt, qlist

I want to compare two Qlist say

```
QList<QSerialPortInfo> port1;
QList<QSerialPortInfo> port2;
```

I want to implement it in `if` condition such that

```
if (port1 != port2)
{
// do something
}
```

but it seems that it doesn't work like that I have read the documentation for QList and there is this member

```
operator!=(const QList<T> &other) const
```

Any Idea how to implement it, please don't go and say ohh I am not going to give you the solution but here is a tip. I am not a student and this is not a homework. I am doing my own project in Qt.
thanks guys.

Answer (score 5):

From the [`QList<T>::operator!=` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#operator-not-eq)...

> This function requires the value type to have an implementation of
>   operator==().

Unfortunately there is no valid `operator==` defined for `QSerialPortInfo` but you can easily implement your own...

```
bool operator== (const QSerialPortInfo &lhs, const QSerialPortInfo &rhs)
{
  return lhs.manufacturer() == rhs.manufacturer()
    && lhs.serialNumber() == rhs.serialNumber();
}
```

The code shown assumes that a `QSerialPortInfo` instance can be uniquely identified by its manufacturer and serial number.